# Why is my python selenium program unable to use locators on one specific website?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a bot that can sign into a page using selenium, but I keep getting the error that my locator strategy is 0 and therefore unsupported.

My code for the scraping is this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

ff = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Rohan\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
ff.get("<website>")
email = ff.find_element(By.NAME, 'email')
email.clear()
email.send_keys("<email>")
ff.close()
```

And it keeps outputting this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: 
Message: invalid argument: Unsupported locator strategy: 0
```

I have tried downgrading selenium, which didn't work. I've printed out By.NAME and it's equal to "name", not 0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the website? Can you add it to the post

Comment: I don’t exactly want to post that, is there anything in particular that could help you? Could I post the page’s slightly edited html?

Comment: Help us to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you using Selenium 3 or 4?

Comment: I’m using selenium 4.9.0

Answer (score 0):

So, the find_element implementation in selenium4 has two keyword arguments like this:

```
def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None)
```

I would try:

```
ff.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="email")
```

The source code gave me a smell that your single quotes around 'email' could be problematic. Which is a bug would need fixing, I'll investigate that